# Was the "pin to start" feature in Windows 8 Google Chrome removed?

Tags: windows-8, google-chrome

I used to be able to pin a website to my Start screen in the Windows 8 version of Google Chrome, but now I can't find that feature. Was it removed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it was removed.

Workaround:

1. Create a shortcut for Chrome somewhere, you will need to keep the shortcut around - so maybe `My Documents\Shortcuts`
2. Right Click > Properties
3. In the "Target" field, append a space and then the URL to the website.

   - Example Contents: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome.exe" http://superuser.com/questions`
4. Customize the title/icon/etc
5. Click "OK"
6. Try opening it to verify.
7. Right Click > Pin To Start

Comment: Any idea why such a useful feature would be removed?

Comment: Not sure. Maybe they are working on making some live tile versions or something. Though, I haven't seen any official reason why.

Answer (score 0):

The option to pin to a website (menu, tools, create desktop shortcut, rt click on shortcut, pin to start) IS still there but you must launch Chrome from the desktop, not win 8.